# How to know that an Activity has been started by a given Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using the code given [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) to login to Twitter. The callback url is `oauth://t4jsample` and the `intent-filter` is shown below.

It works perfectly, but when `MainActivity` is started from this `Intent`, I'd like to reload the `Fragment` containing my Twitter login `Button` to show a message "you're logged as ...".

How can I know that `MainActivity` has been started by the `Intent` sent by the Twitter web page? I can get the `Intent`'s action, but how can I make sure that it has not been sent by something else?

**intent filter**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" ... >
    ...
    <intent-filter>    
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="t4jsample"
            android:scheme="oauth" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can make use of getIntent().getData(),which will give the Uri of the data associated with the intent.If it matches the oauth://t4jsample,then u can be sure that it came from twitter and u can do ur changes accordingly